# OutputStream gives "close failed: EIO (I/O error)" while deleting file runtime

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inputstream, outputstream

Gives an Error `Error : close failed: EIO (I/O error)` when i delete file which is currently writing mode.

Actually i am downloading file using `AsyncTask` and i can cancel this download in between.
For stop this download i am deleting that file and checking continuously in while loop of writing data that file is exists or not, if file not found then i am breaking that loop and returning to `onPostExecute` but its throwing an error.

So how can i remove that error and use `output.flush()` and `output.close()` properly?

MyCode is:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    int count;
    try {
    URL url = new URL(taskHolder.fileUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

    outputDir = PROCESSING_PATH + taskHolder.fileName;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputDir);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024*4];

    long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        output.write(data, 0, count);

        /**
         * When user cancelling downloads, 
         * file will be deleted from that 
         * folder so here have to check 
         * file is exists or not.
         */
        if(!(new File(outputDir).exists())) {
        returnValue = "cancelled";
        break;
        }

    }

    returnValue = "1";
    output.flush();
    returnValue = "2";
    output.close();
    returnValue = "3";
    input.close();
    returnValue = "4";

    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error : "+e.getLocalizedMessage() + " : " + returnValue);
    returnValue = null;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: "when i delete file which is currently writing mode" --that should not happen on the first place. If you are going to delete the file, it shouldn't be accessed by a write operation simultaneously. Try to stop other operations on it, before attempting delete.  
Consider calling all "close()" functions(related to the data/stream/parsing) with delete

Comment: How can i stop it in between of execution. @user2450263

Comment: don't have to "stop" it, just ensure the writing stops when you are deleting that file, like a NPE check before accessing a variable.  Post the logcat, on which line do you get the error

Comment: I am getting error on `output.flush()` and `output.close()`